# Is there a jQuery container selector for CCK fields?

Tags: javascript, entities

I'm using a Drupal module called FitVids, which makes iframe videos and images responsive. But i'm also using the YouTube Field module and the fitvids module is distorting the YouTube Field module's video player. So I need to add the CCK field to the exclude list for the video container using the jquery :not() selector.

Comment: Have you tried to simply inspect both with firebug or something?

Comment: No. Let me see if that helps. Thanks for the advice.